# Deleting IE Cache and Cookies using C# Code in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, internet-explorer

I am using a WebBrowser control in my WPF application and I am looking to clear the IE cookie cache from code.

I have attempted to use the following code

```
string[] Cookies = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Cookies));
foreach (string currentFile in Cookies)
{
  try
  {
    System.IO.File.Delete(currentFile);
  }

  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
  }
}
```

This deletes the files from the specified folder, but when I navigate back using the WebBrowser control, the cookies reappear as though they were never deleted.

This might be the right result, as I am assuming that the Environment.SpecialFolder.Cookies folder is in AppData which is a current snapshot of what the user is up to.

If I open up IE, and do a hard delete of cookies and cache I get the expected output in my app.

Is there a way to do this action in code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Microsoft KB Article will help you better and clear the entire Cache.

[Link To Refer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326201)

However, You can try the following solution too.

```
string[] InterNetCache = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache));
```

Comment: Thanks. The linked article is really great. We made a design decision on my current project to offload this functionality to a separate layer which itself runs a script to delete the cache. as described in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274397/clearing-ie-cache-programatically-vs-inetcpl-cpl-clearmytracksbyprocess

Answer (score 2):

Using below function one can delete cookie for the certain host name. If whole cache needs to be cleared then condition "**if(sourceUrlName.Contains(hostEntry) && sourceUrlName.ToLower().Contains("cookie"))**" 
should be removed.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Internets the set cookie.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="lpszUrlName">Name of the LPSZ URL.</param>
    /// <param name="lpszCookieName">Name of the LPSZ cookie.</param>
    /// <param name="lpszCookieData">The LPSZ cookie data.</param>
    /// <returns><c>true</c> if XXXX, <c>false</c> otherwise</returns>
    [DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool InternetSetCookie(string lpszUrlName, string lpszCookieName, string lpszCookieData);

    /// <summary>
    /// Internets the get cookie.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="lpszUrl">The LPSZ URL.</param>
    /// <param name="lpszCookieName">Name of the LPSZ cookie.</param>
    /// <param name="lpszCookieData">The LPSZ cookie data.</param>
    /// <param name="lpdwSize">Size of the LPDW.</param>
    /// <returns><c>true</c> if XXXX, <c>false</c> otherwise</returns>
    [DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool InternetGetCookie(string lpszUrl, string lpszCookieName, StringBuilder lpszCookieData, ref int lpdwSize);

    /// <summary>
    /// Finds the first URL cache entry.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="lpszUrlSearchPattern">The LPSZ URL search pattern.</param>
    /// <param name="lpFirstCacheEntryInfo">The lp first cache entry info.</param>
    /// <param name="lpdwFirstCacheEntryInfoBufferSize">Size of the LPDW first cache entry info buffer.</param>
    /// <returns>IntPtr.</returns>
    [DllImport(@"wininet",
        SetLastError = true,
        CharSet = CharSet.Auto,
        EntryPoint = "FindFirstUrlCacheEntryA",
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindFirstUrlCacheEntry(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string lpszUrlSearchPattern,
        IntPtr lpFirstCacheEntryInfo,
        ref int lpdwFirstCacheEntryInfoBufferSize);

    /// <summary>
    /// Finds the next URL cache entry.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hFind">The h find.</param>
    /// <param name="lpNextCacheEntryInfo">The lp next cache entry info.</param>
    /// <param name="lpdwNextCacheEntryInfoBufferSize">Size of the LPDW next cache entry info buffer.</param>
    /// <returns><c>true</c> if XXXX, <c>false</c> otherwise</returns>
    [DllImport(@"wininet",
        SetLastError = true,
        CharSet = CharSet.Auto,
        EntryPoint = "FindNextUrlCacheEntryA",
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool FindNextUrlCacheEntry(
        IntPtr hFind,
        IntPtr lpNextCacheEntryInfo,
        ref int lpdwNextCacheEntryInfoBufferSize);

    /// <summary>
    /// Deletes the URL cache entry.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="lpszUrlName">Name of the LPSZ URL.</param>
    /// <returns><c>true</c> if XXXX, <c>false</c> otherwise</returns>
    [DllImport(@"wininet",
        SetLastError = true,
        CharSet = CharSet.Auto,
        EntryPoint = "DeleteUrlCacheEntryA",
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool DeleteUrlCacheEntry(
        IntPtr lpszUrlName);


    /// <summary>
    /// Clears the IE cache.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="url">The URL.</param>
    public static void ClearIECache(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            // No more items have been found.
            const int ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS = 259;

            string hostEntry = new Uri(url).Host;

            // Local variables
            int cacheEntryInfoBufferSizeInitial = 0;
            int cacheEntryInfoBufferSize = 0;
            IntPtr cacheEntryInfoBuffer = IntPtr.Zero;
            INTERNET_CACHE_ENTRY_INFOA internetCacheEntry;
            IntPtr enumHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            bool returnValue = false;

            // Start to delete URLs that do not belong to any group.
            enumHandle = FindFirstUrlCacheEntry(null, IntPtr.Zero, ref cacheEntryInfoBufferSizeInitial);
            if (enumHandle == IntPtr.Zero && ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS == Marshal.GetLastWin32Error())
                return;

            cacheEntryInfoBufferSize = cacheEntryInfoBufferSizeInitial;
            cacheEntryInfoBuffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(cacheEntryInfoBufferSize);
            enumHandle = FindFirstUrlCacheEntry(null, cacheEntryInfoBuffer, ref cacheEntryInfoBufferSizeInitial);

            while (true)
            {
                internetCacheEntry = (INTERNET_CACHE_ENTRY_INFOA)Marshal.PtrToStructure(cacheEntryInfoBuffer, typeof(INTERNET_CACHE_ENTRY_INFOA));

                string sourceUrlName = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(internetCacheEntry.lpszSourceUrlName);
                cacheEntryInfoBufferSizeInitial = cacheEntryInfoBufferSize;

                if (sourceUrlName.Contains(hostEntry) && sourceUrlName.ToLower().Contains("cookie"))
                {
                    DeleteUrlCacheEntry(internetCacheEntry.lpszSourceUrlName);
                }

                returnValue = FindNextUrlCacheEntry(enumHandle, cacheEntryInfoBuffer, ref cacheEntryInfoBufferSizeInitial);

                if (!returnValue && ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS == Marshal.GetLastWin32Error())
                {
                    break;
                }
                if (!returnValue && cacheEntryInfoBufferSizeInitial > cacheEntryInfoBufferSize)
                {
                    cacheEntryInfoBufferSize = cacheEntryInfoBufferSizeInitial;
                    cacheEntryInfoBuffer = Marshal.ReAllocHGlobal(cacheEntryInfoBuffer, (IntPtr)cacheEntryInfoBufferSize);
                    returnValue = FindNextUrlCacheEntry(enumHandle, cacheEntryInfoBuffer, ref cacheEntryInfoBufferSizeInitial);
                }
            }

            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(cacheEntryInfoBuffer);
        }
        catch
        {
            //error
        }
    }



    /// <summary>
/// Struct INTERNET_CACHE_ENTRY_INFOA
/// </summary>
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 80)]
public struct INTERNET_CACHE_ENTRY_INFOA
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public uint dwStructSize;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public IntPtr lpszSourceUrlName;
    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public IntPtr lpszLocalFileName;
    [FieldOffset(12)]
    public uint CacheEntryType;
    [FieldOffset(16)]
    public uint dwUseCount;
    [FieldOffset(20)]
    public uint dwHitRate;
    [FieldOffset(24)]
    public uint dwSizeLow;
    [FieldOffset(28)]
    public uint dwSizeHigh;
    [FieldOffset(32)]
    public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME LastModifiedTime;
    [FieldOffset(40)]
    public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ExpireTime;
    [FieldOffset(48)]
    public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME LastAccessTime;
    [FieldOffset(56)]
    public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME LastSyncTime;
    [FieldOffset(64)]
    public IntPtr lpHeaderInfo;
    [FieldOffset(68)]
    public uint dwHeaderInfoSize;
    [FieldOffset(72)]
    public IntPtr lpszFileExtension;
    [FieldOffset(76)]
    public uint dwReserved;
    [FieldOffset(76)]
    public uint dwExemptDelta;
}
```