# I want to remove temporary files

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer

I tried to

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache));

foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
{
    file.Delete();
}
foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in di.GetDirectories())
{
    dir.Delete(true);
}
```

and

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("rundll32.exe", "InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 8");
```

.

First one is not working.

The other method works, but there are issues with compatibility and loading windows.

Is there another good way?

Comment: Please don't add unnecessary tags. From the information you have provided, this question isn't remotely related to WinForms.

Comment: "*First one is not working.*" is not a technical description of a problem.

Comment: "Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache" path requires some kind of permission. Did you check it?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274397/clearing-ie-cache-programmatically-vs-inetcpl-cpl-clearmytracksbyprocess?noredirect=1&lq=1 , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167984/deleting-ie-cache-and-cookies-using-c-sharp-code-in-wpf ,

Comment: The first code builds successfully but the form doesn't pop up.

Comment: I didn't check the permissions, but I verified that the path was properly received through the messagebox. 
thanks I'll check.

Comment: The first method will not work if the files are opened or in use by some process. It will raise an error. Can you please inform us with some more detailed, what issue you are having with second way?

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I was using it in another process, so I got the error. The second way is to not delete only certain files.

Comment: Looks like you want to keep some files. If you know the file name that you want to keep then try to check and match the file name while deleting the files using first approach.

Answer (score -1):

The first method is correct and there's nothing wrong about it. But if you want maybe something that "looks" cleaner, while it does the same thing, you can do something like this:

- Encapsulate the cleaning logic in an extension method
- Call the extension method on the directory.

An example approach can be found as an answer to a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1288796/10994887)